# Custom validation of textbox in WPF

Tags: wpf, validation, textbox

So I'm trying to do something along this example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx

My Textbox currently looks like this:

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="118,60,0,0" Name="CreateUserCPRTextbox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"  >
                <TextBox.Text>

                    <Binding Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <validators:TextRangeValidator
                        MinimumLength="10"
                        MaximumLength="10"
                        ErrorMessage="ID has to be 10 letters" />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>

            </TextBox>
```

I've directly copied my TextRangeValidator from the example on that website. Nothing happens when I lose focus on the textbox. No matter what I type in it. Any Ideas? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set the Validation.ErrorTemplate? It is defined as below in the Application.Resources in the example.You may have missed that

```
<Application.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">

                            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                Foreground="Orange"
                                Margin="5" 
                                FontSize="12pt"
                                Text="{Binding ElementName=MyAdorner, 
                           Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                            </TextBlock>

                            <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="3">
                                <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyAdorner" />
                            </Border>

                        </DockPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                   Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
```

**EDIT**

Your default value is not triggering the validation routine.To force it to validate for default value you have to set

```
<validators:TextRangeValidator ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"
                        MinimumLength="10"
                        MaximumLength="10"
                        ErrorMessage="ID has to be 10 letters" />
```

Comment: I haven't done this as I thought it would use the default. Where it makes the border of the textbox red? I wasn't sure where to fit this code in - that's why I didn't use it hehe.. I am totally new at WPF.

Comment: Actually the default red border should appear.But it will not show your error message

Comment: and where is <Application.Resources> supposed to go? what do I put it inside?

Comment: <Application.Resources> are application level resources which is available through out your application.It is in the App.xaml file

Comment: Ah thanks, but as we thought it did not change much. Any other ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set  `ValidatesOnDataErrors=True` in binding for Text to make it work

Comment: Doesn't seem like the Textbox got that attribute? or where would you add it?

Answer (score 0):

**WPF TextBox Validation**

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxInError" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>                        

                        <Grid>
                            <Polygon Points="20,10,20,0 0,0"
                            Stroke="Black"
                            StrokeThickness="1"
                            Fill="Red"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=adorner, 
                               Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorner"/>


                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner"  VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                            <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="1" />
                        </AdornedElementPlaceholder>


                        </Grid>

                        <Border Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="right" Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                            Width="150" Height="20" CornerRadius="5"
                            ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, 
                                      Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                            <TextBlock Text= "{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, 
                                      Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                               FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="white" Width="250" />                               


                        </Border>


                    </DockPanel>



                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />

            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>        


    </Style>
```

Comment: You need to say what you've actually done to give some guidance on how this is an answer, rather than just post code